# Can not manage to launch the site with sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I have a small problem with sinatra.

I recovered a project made ​​Sinatra, and I made a bundle install just that all goes well but when I made ​​a

> ruby app.rb

well, he told me

> kernel_require.rb:110:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError)

I do not understand the problem or just because it is well require 'sass'

thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gem install sass
```

in the terminal; it's a gem for working with a different kinds of CSS.

Also see http://sass-lang.com/ for information about what it is.

Comment: If there are other dependencies ( "cannot load such file " -- name) then try a "gem install (name)" on it.

Comment: A better way is to include the missing gems in the `Gemfile` and do `bundle install`.